# Minimizing Frobenius norm of a special type

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A$ is a symmetric matrix, find $X$ that solves
$$\mathop {\min }\limits_X {\left\| {A - X{X^T}} \right\|_F}$$

I think that the problem can be solved using eigenvalue or singular value decomposition technics. $XX^T=A$ seems an obvious solution, but the problem is that $XX^T$ is positive semidefinite, while $A$ may not be, although they are both symmetric.

At this point I am thinking about taking eigenvalue decomposition of A, then replace the negative eigenvalues in the middle diagonal matrix with 0-s (denote the resulting matrix by $\bar{A}$). But am having difficulties to understand why  $XX^T=\bar{A}$ gives the $X$ with minimal distance from A.

Comment: Such brief notes will often be closed as "off-topic" due to lack of context.  You may not intend it as such, but a bare imperative sentence will give many Readers the impression you expect them to do your assignments for you, which is not the purpose of this Community.  Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Formulation

I'm trying to solve a similar problem. I don't think this answers your question, but I hope it might be useful to you.

\begin{align*}
\mathop{\min}\limits_X {\left\| {A - X{X^T}} \right\|_F} &\equiv \mathop {\min }\limits_X {\left\| {A - X{X^T}} \right\|_F^2} \\
&= \mathop{\min}\limits_X {\left\langle {A - X{X^T}},{A - X{X^T}} \right\rangle_F} \\
&= \mathop{\min}\limits_X \Big( \left\langle {A,A} \right\rangle_F -2 \left\langle {A,XX^T} \right\rangle_F + \left\langle {XX^T,XX^T} \right\rangle_F \Big) \\
&= \mathop{\min}\limits_X \Big( \left\langle {XX^T,XX^T} \right\rangle_F -2 \left\langle {A,XX^T} \right\rangle_F \Big) \\
&= \mathop{\min}\limits_X \Big( \operatorname{Tr}\left( {XX^TXX^T} \right) -2 \operatorname{Tr}\left( {AXX^T} \right) \Big) \\
\end{align*}

If you apply the SVD as

\begin{align*}
X &= U\Sigma V^T \\
A &= BDB^T,
\end{align*}

then this is
\begin{align*}
&\mathop{\min}\limits_X \Big( \operatorname{Tr}\left( {U\Sigma^4U^T} \right) -2 \operatorname{Tr}\left( {BDB^TU\Sigma^2U^T} \right) \Big) \\
=& \mathop{\min}\limits_X \Big( \operatorname{Tr}\left( {\Sigma^4} \right)-2 \operatorname{Tr}\left( {BDB^TU\Sigma^2U^T} \right) \Big).
\end{align*}

### Useful Properties of the Trace

The trace allows cycling the product in its argument.  Taking matrices of various (compatible) sizes, because the trace is defined for square matrices, the outer dimensions of the matrix product must match. These are equivalent:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(ABCD) = \operatorname{Tr}(BCDA) = \operatorname{Tr}(CDAB) = \operatorname{Tr}(DABC)$$