# Solving Frobenius minimization with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A$ is a symmetric matrix, find $X$ that solves
$$\mathop {\min }\limits_X {\left\| {A - X{X^T}} \right\|_F}$$

I think that the problem can be solved using eigenvalue or singular value decomposition technics. $XX^T=A$ seems an obvious solution, but the problem is that $XX^T$ is positive semidefinite, while $A$ may not be, although they are both symmetric.

At this point I am thinking about taking eigenvalue decomposition of A, then replacing the negative eigenvalues in the middle diagonal matrix with 0-s (denote the resulting matrix by $\bar{A}$). But am having difficulties to understand why  $XX^T=\bar{A}$ gives the $X$ with minimal distance from A.

Comment: The paragraph "nearest orthogonal matrix" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition may be relevant.

Comment: It is ***very*** rude to repost the same question after it was put on hold by the community. You should wait for the reopening of your old question. Regardless of whether the [old one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402537/minimizing-frobenius-norm-of-a-special-type) can be reopened, I think this reposting must be closed, if not deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is the correct one: Compute the eigenvalue decomposition $A = USU^T$, set $S_0 = \sqrt{\max(S,0)}$ (element wise) and set $X = US_0$. The reference that justifies this is

[N. Higham, Computing a nearest symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, Linear algebra and its applications vol. 103 (1988), 103-118.](https://scholar.google.gr/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=EYlMkOgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=EYlMkOgAAAAJ:2osOgNQ5qMEC)

Answer (score 2):

A multiplication by a unitary matrix preserves the Frobenius norm of a matrix, so if $A= V D V^T$ is the [spectral decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of $A$, for some $X$ we have $XX^T = V D_{\geq 0} V^T$ (since the RHS is a positive semidefinite matrix) and in such a case $\|A-XX^T\|_F=\|D-D_{\geq 0}\|_F$ is just the $l_2$ norm of the negative part of the spectrum of $A$. If $XX^T$ and $A$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable then $\|A-XX^T\|_F$ is greater than that quantity, hence:

$$ \min_{X}\|A-XX^T\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{\substack{\lambda\in\text{Spec} A\\ \lambda<0}}\lambda^2}$$
and an interesting consequence is that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $XX^T$ is an "approximate Cholesky decomposition" of $A$, i.e. if $\|A-XX^T\|_F$ is small, the $l_2$ norm of the negative part of the spectrum of $A$ is bounded in terms of the approximation error.

Comment: Hi Jack , clearly the problem is equivalent to prove that " If $XX^T$ and $A$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable then $\|A-XX^T\|_F\geq \|D-D_{\geq 0}\|_F$". You admit this result. Have you a one line proof ?